# How to compile parts of code with different floating-point options?

Tags: c++, pragma, icc

I'm optimizing some C++ code using the Intel compiler and I need to use different compile options in some parts of code, in a single source file.

I know the `#pragma pack` directive can change structure members' alignment inside code but I'd like to know if there are other directives for other options.

In my case, I'm compiling my code with the `/fp:precise` option but I'd like to use `/fp:fast` in some parts of the code.

Comment: Be aware that `#pragma pack` changes the structure layout, i.e. it essentially changes the structure definition. If you use it in some translation units but not in others which share access to an instance of that structure your code will not work.

Comment: Every compilation unit is compiled separately. The resulting object files are linked together. You can use different compiler flags for each compilation unit.

Comment: The question is too broad and lacks own research. You say "I'd like to know if there are other directives for other options". The obvious answer is "Duh, yes." The place to look is Intel's documentation for their compiler, specifically https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/compiler-option-details/optimization-options.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select *some* floating-point options *for specific functions* using [`#pragma float_control`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/float-control?view=vs-2019) (supported by both `MSVC` and the Intel® C++ compiler).

However, note the important caveat given in the linked document:

> The **float_control** pragma doesn't have the same behavior as the /fp
>   compiler option. The **float_control** pragma only governs part of the
>   floating-point behavior. It must be combined with fp_contract and
>   fenv_access pragmas to recreate the **/fp** compiler options ...

Using this and related `#pragma` directives **will** allow you to compile code sections ***in a single translation unit*** with different options.

According to the table shown in the linked document (just below the quoted text), the *only* difference between `/fp:precise` and `/fp:fast` is controlled by the `float_control` pragma (but you will need others to switch from `/fp:strict`), so code like the following would allow one function in a given source file to use the `fast` option:

```cpp
#pragma float_control( precise, off, push ) // Save current setting and turn off /fp:precise
double FastFloatFunc(double x)
{
    double y = x * (x - 1);
    // Do something: Generated code will use /fp:fast
    return y;
}
#pragma float_control(pop) // Restore file's default settings
```